# Joomla 3 Bootstrap Button wont show glyphicons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, joomla, glyphicons

I would like to integrate Bootstrap Buttons in one of my views.

But the integration does not really work. The button will be displayed, but the glyphicons are not there.

As a simple example, I integrated the example from the bootstrap homepage
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star
</button
```

Is there something special I have to integrate, when Iam interested in using
Bootstrap buttons and glyphicons?

Answer (score 4):

If you're referring to **Joomla 3 and /administrator** views, Joomla uses Bootstrap 2.3, so you will need to use [the button classes](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons) and [the icon classes from that version](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons). e.g.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-large">
  <i class="icon-star"></i> Star
</button>
```

That will result in:

[image: rendered example of bootstrap 2.x button in Joomla 3]

In addition there are a sub-set of `ico-moon` font-icons in `/media/jui`, you can find [a visual reference](http://kyleledbetter.com/jui/icons/) to them on [Kyle Ledbetter's web site](http://kyleledbetter.com/).

Finally, you can also find them in `/media/jui/fonts/IcoMoon.dev.commented.svg` an annotated file with icon descriptions that you can search.

If you're referring to **Joomla 3 front-end** views or *versions prior to Joomla 3* how are you loading Bootstrap 3? Can you see the Bootstrap files referenced in the HTML output by your view?